# How do I return a double array containing decimal numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers, double, decimal

This is my first question, so I hope I explain this correctly ;-)

I need to create a method that takes in a double array, numbers, and returns a new array containing the square of each element in numbers. (Any help and guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!)

The parameters I have been given are as follows:

```
<param name="numbers">Input array</param>
<returns>double array</returns>

        public double[] PowerArray(double[] numbers)
```

This is what I've written so far, but it returns double numbers. I need the return to contain decimal numbers.

```
        {
            double[] PowerArray = Array.ConvertAll(numbers, i => i * i);

            return PowerArray;
         }
```

My instructions are to return my answers following this example:  double[] input = { -2.2, 0, 1.1, 3 } should return double[] [4.84, 0, 1.21. 9]. My return is giving me double[] [4.840000000000001, 0, 1.2100000000000002, 9].

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your existing code. [It works just fine to me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TASktN). What do you mean "return decimal"? Your method says it returns doubles.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!! Yes, it works; however, my instructions are to return my answers following this example:  double[] input = { -2.2, 0, 1.1, 3 } should return double[] [4.84, 0, 1.21. 9]. My return is giving me double[] [4.840000000000001, 0, 1.2100000000000002, 9].

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](//docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004) This is how all floating point math works. If you want to avoid this floating point issue, don't use doubles, use decimals for everything.

Comment: Since floating point numbers are inexact it is somewhat common to restrict the number of decimals when printing the numbers. So `(-2.2 * -2.2).ToString()` should give '4.84', while `(-2.2 * -2.2).ToString("R")` should give the full string, '4,8400000000000007'. The debugger may show the full number however.

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting the [fundamental nature of floating point math](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004). Floating point numbers are *approximations*. You don't want an approximation, therefore it's inappropriate to use this data type.

Instead, use `decimal` to perform the math. You can then cast the result back to a `double` if you really need it to be.

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

public double[] PowerArray(double[] numbers)
{
    return numbers
        .Select(x => (decimal)x) // convert the element to a decimal
        .Select(x => x * x) // perform decimal-level multiplication
        .Select(x => (double)x) // convert the result back to a double
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is working perfectly!! Your answer is much appreciated. I wish I could give it an upvote, but I am too new I guess. THANK YOU!!! :-)